# optional controlled / uncontrolled React component with conditional React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

IMO, React Hooks useState is a perfect fit for a pattern to optional using value from props or use own state, but the lint showed some error when I use hook conditionally.

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oo03wnw2j5)

I tried to use hooks with condition as below but with eslint error `React hook useState is called conditionally`. According to this [explanation from doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), `React relies on the order in which Hooks are called`.

```
const Counter = ({ value, onChange, defaultValue = 0 }) => {
  const [count, onCountChange] =
    typeof value === "undefined" ? useState(defaultValue) : [value, onChange];
  return (
    <div>
      {count.toString()}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          onCountChange(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
function App() {
  const [count, onCountChange] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        Uncontrolled Counter
        <Counter />
      </div>
      <div>
        Controlled Counter
        <Counter value={count} onChange={onCountChange} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I use hooks to achieve same function as below  class Component ?

```
class CounterClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.defaultValue || 0
  };
  render() {
    const isControlled = typeof this.props.defaultValue === "undefined";
    const count = isControlled ? this.props.value : this.state.value;

    return (
      <div>
        {count.toString()}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            isControlled &&
              this.props.onChange &&
              this.props.onChange(this.props.value + 1);
            !isControlled && this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
          }}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or this kind props/state optional way in one component is wrong?

I learnt the `"defaultValue"`, `"value"`, `"onChange"` API naming and idea from React JSX `<input>` component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could split your component into fully controlled and fully uncontrolled. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwr7zvy5l4)

```
const CounterRepresentation = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    {value.toString()}
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        onChange(value + 1);
      }}
    >
      +
    </button>
  </div>
);

const Uncontrolled = ({ defaultValue = 0 }) => {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(defaultValue);
  return <CounterRepresentation value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

// Either use representation directly or uncontrolled
const Counter = ({ value, onChange, defaultValue = 0 }) => {
  return typeof value === "undefined" ? (
    <Uncontrolled defaultValue={defaultValue} />
  ) : (
    <CounterRepresentation value={value} onChange={onChange} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Wow!! I think this is the right answer I need. I think this is a good example of using the concept of `representational component` and `container component` ( or smart / dump component ) .

Answer (score 2):

Great question! I think this can be solved with hooks by making the `useState` call unconditional and only making the part conditional where you decide which state you render and what change handler you use.

I've just released a hook which solves this: [use-optionally-controlled-state](https://github.com/amannn/react-hooks/tree/master/packages/use-optionally-controlled-state)

**Usage:**

```
import useOptionallyControlledState from 'use-optionally-controlled-state';
 
function Expander({
  expanded: controlledExpanded,
  initialExpanded = false,
  onChange
}) {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useOptionallyControlledState({
    controlledValue: controlledExpanded,
    initialValue: initialExpanded,
    onChange
  });
 
  function onToggle() {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  }
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onToggle} type="button">
        Toggle
      </button>
      {expanded && <div>{children}</div>}
    </>
  );
}

// Usage of the component:

// Controlled
<Expander expanded={expanded} onChange={onExpandedChange} />
 
// Uncontrolled using the default value for the `initialExpanded` prop
<Expander />
 
// Uncontrolled, but with a change handler if the owner wants to be notified
<Expander initialExpanded onChange={onExpandedChange} />
```

By using a hook to implement this, you don't have to wrap an additional component around and you can theoretically apply this to multiple props within the same component (e.g. a `<Prompt isOpen={isOpen} inputValue={inputValue} />` component where both props are optionally controlled).